# Rails 4 model path delete not working despite correct HTML being generated

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Here is my index.html.erb file (the relevant part):

```
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', dish_path(dish), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

and

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/dishes/4" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

is the HTML generated. I know Javascript is enabled because I have tons of Jquery being used all over the place correctly.

Here are my routes:

```
                    dishes GET    /dishes(.:format)                         dishes#index
                           POST   /dishes(.:format)                         dishes#create
                  new_dish GET    /dishes/new(.:format)                     dishes#new
                 edit_dish GET    /dishes/:id/edit(.:format)                dishes#edit
                      dish GET    /dishes/:id(.:format)                     dishes#show
                           PATCH  /dishes/:id(.:format)                     dishes#update
                           PUT    /dishes/:id(.:format)                     dishes#update
                           DELETE /dishes/:id(.:format)                     dishes#destroy
```

What is the next step I should do to figure out why the model isn't getting destroyed and why the popup isnt even showing up?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: I presume you have a method in your controller to deal with this? @ArthurCollé

Comment: I did, but it was incorrectly named. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had some javascript code that despite seeming completely unrelated, was causing the popup to not appear.

Additionally, my 'delete' method in my controller was supposed to be called 'destroy'